# Quero fazer o scraping de uma página, porém não consigo pegar um texto que possui "&nbsp" nele

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Bom, o título diz tudo, quero pegar o preço de um produto do site https://www.pontofrio.com.br/, que se encontra assim:

```
<span class="nm-price-value" itemprop="price">R$&nbsp;367,60</span>
```

Utilizando esse código:

```
import bs4
import requests

def get_page(url):
    r = requests.get(url)

    try:
        r.raise_for_status()
        page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        return page

    except Exception as e:
        return False

def pontofrio(search):
    soup = get_page(f'https://search3.pontofrio.com.br/busca?q={search}')

    price = [i.getText() for i in soup.select('.nm-price-value')]
    product = [i.getText().upper() for i in soup.select('.nm-product-name a')]
    link = [i.get('href') for i in soup.select('.nm-product-name a')]

    return product, price, link
```

Sendo que as listas product e link retornam normalmente, mas a lista price está retornando:

```
['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']
```

Por favor ajudem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é que o preço na verdade não existe na página! As páginas do site do ponto frio, assim como muitas outras na internet, são disponibilizadas **sem o preço**, e só depois esse preço é colocado na página através de código feito em javascript que é executado em seu navegador após o carregamento.

Portanto, ao inspecionar o código da página com seu navegador, o javascript já terá executado e completado os elementos de forma dinâmica, por isso você encontrará os preços lá. Como o BeautifulSoup não executa javascript, na página que ele parseou os preços não existem.

Isso é muito comum nas páginas da web hoje em dia, que são bastante dinâmicas. Te deixando com duas opções:

1. Analisar o código javascript da página e descobrir de onde ele tira o preço. Neste caso parece vir da url `https://preco.api-pontofrio.com.br/V1/Produtos/PrecoVenda/`. Você pode ir lendo e acompanhando o código javascript até encontrar uma forma de imitar o que ele faz para recuperar esses preços, quais parâmetros passar, etc. Não é uma tarefa fácil mas o código ficaria bastante otimizado pois seria código python sem precisar abrir um navegador de verdade, que seria a segunda opção:
2. Utilizar um navegador de verdade, que rode javascript. A biblioteca `Selenium` permite que você abra e controle uma janela de navegador real através do seu script. Como a página abrirá em um navegador, o javascript vai funcionar e você consegue pegar esses preços. O lado negativo é que abrir um navegador é pesado e lento, além de carregar vários elementos e imagens desnecessárias ao processo, portanto, não seria tão eficiente quanto acessar diretamente a fonte.